# circumvent asp event handlers

Tags: javascript, .net, browser, redirect, enter

I want to cause a browser redirect by changing the value of "window.location" in some javascript in a VB.Net page.  The code below works correctly when I click the "Go" button: The alert appears and the browser is successfully redirected. The same should happen if I press "enter" from inside the text, box this doesn't work. I do see the alert, but the browser stays on the same page.

The "enter" functionality starts working if I remove the references to ASP master pages, so maybe something in there is handling the keypress event and killing the redirect instruction?

Btw, I was originally doing this "normally" using .Net components and doing a postback when the submit button is clicked.  But *that* was weirdly causing the target page to load twice, causing page flicker and generally being inefficient.  I didn't see any reason to involve all that .Net overhead anyway, so I hoped to do it with straightforward client-side scripting.

Does anyone know how I can get the "enter" key functionality to work in spite of .Net interference?  Or am I barking up the wrong tree and should go back to a regular .Net postback?

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

<script type="text/javascript">
  function clickHandler() {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown");
    var entityID = document.getElementById("textOne").value;
    var destination = dropdown.options(dropdown.selectedIndex).value + entityID;
    alert(destination);
    location = destination;
  }

  function goIfEnterPressed() {
    if ((event.which && event.which != 13) || (event.keyCode && event.keyCode != 13)) {
      return false;
    }
    clickHandler();
  }

</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
  <select id="dropdown">
    <option value="Page1.aspx?typeOneID=">One</option>
    <option value="Page2.aspx?typeTwoID=">Two</option>
    <option value="Page3.aspx?typeThreeID=">Three</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <input id="textOne" onkeypress="goIfEnterPressed()"/>
  <br />
  <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="clickHandler()" />
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your enter event might be getting caught by the .Net javascript stuff.  Normally in a case like this I would to prevent the default behaviour of the event before doing my work.  I don't know if you use jQuery or not, but the code would be something like:

```
  $('#buttonid').keydown(function(e) {
     if (e.keyCode == 13) {
       e.preventDefault();
       //do whatever you want here.
     }
   });
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm actually not using jQuery.  Importing the whole library for this one problem would feel like nuking a mosquito, even if it's a very annoying mosquito :) Do you have an idea how I might do it with everyday native javascript?

Comment: Double checked, apparently preventDefault() is implemented as a method on the event object in JavaScript - so you should be able to do the same basic thing in standard javascript as well. (So event.preventdefault() should work). http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html

Comment: Aha! Thank you for the suggestion. It turns out that preventDefault is not implemented in IE, but to do the same thing you set window.event.returnValue = false. For non-IE browsers you can use preventDefault(). I should be on the right path now. It seems like the more you can avoid .Net when using .Net the better off you are!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a button somewhere inside your MasterPage's content? This doesn't sound like it's a .NET issue, it sounds more like it could be a misunderstanding of HTML standards. Because all your content is inside a single `<form>` element, the browser will submit the page based on the first `<submit>` button it finds on your page. You can work around this by grouping your content inside an `<asp:Panel>` and setting its `DefaultButton` property to the ID of your submit button. You may also be able to set the `ValidationGroup` property of both your textbox and button to accomplish the same thing, but I can't remember for sure if that works in this situation or if that only affects validation controls.

Comment: I did have these controls in an ASP panel at first, but setting `DefaultButton` and submitting the form must cause a postback, right?  And when it was doing that the target page was loading twice (which is better than 0 times, but still not great).

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing the event into the event handler.  This may be part of your problem - at least in browsers other than IE.

```
<input id="textOne" onkeypress="goIfEnterPressed(event)"/>

function goIfEnterPressed(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        clickHandler();
    }
}
```

Also, did you really want to return false for non-enter keys?  It looks like you're trying to cancel the event, but I don't think it would quite work as written.  But then, if it did work, you would be preventing any text from being typed into the textbox.  Seems like an odd behavior.

Comment: I tend to test on IE first and get that working before testing on other browsers.  You were absolutely right though about not passing in the even on non-IE browsers.  I've now got it working on both fronts.